# Sending temperature sensor's data to Kaa-IOT platform via Z-wave protocol

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, wireless, z-wave

I want to set up some sensors in different places, which are wire connected to my Raspberry PI.

I want to send the collected data's wireless but without using Wifi protocol, The best option for low range IoT projects is Z-wave protocol.
my next target would be using Kaa-IoT Platform as a Cloud Service, which makes my data available regardless of where I am.

I want to implement a circuit like [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-temperature-sensor/).

The Question is, Is there any way to use Z-wave protocol without utilizing any z-wave devices? using z-wave is possible in my scenario?

Buying RaZberry shield would be enough for that?, Which modem should I use to receive signals that send by Razberry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Z-Wave protocol is a method for communicating with Z-Wave devices. Without Z-Wave devices, there's no use for the Z-Wave protocol.

Until very recently, if you wanted to create your own Z-Wave device, you had to spend about $3,000 and sign a non-disclosure agreement to get access to the documentation and tools, and your device had to be certified before you could sell it.

The [Zuno](https://z-uno.z-wave.me/) is a recent DIY Z-Wave board that enables you to create a device that speaks Z-Wave. Boards like the Razberry don't give you that capability. They only give you the capability to issue commands to the Z-Wave controller.

If you're searching for a light-weight communication protocol, check out [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/).

Comment: what about 6LoWPAN, how can I implement above project with this protocol?!

Comment: 6LoWPAN is similar to Wi-Fi (but 802.15.4). Youl should be able to get a shield, but I'm not positive about that. 6LoWPAN is similar to ZigBee.